# @RefreshScope is working without /actuator/refresh being enabled

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kubernetes, spring-cloud

So I am reading about Kubernetes PropertySource in Spring Cloud and how to configure spring to reload a value when it is changed in kubernetes configmap. As far as the doc says:

> refresh (default): Only configuration beans annotated with
> @ConfigurationProperties or @RefreshScope are reloaded. This reload
> level leverages the refresh feature of Spring Cloud Context.

> The RefreshScope is a bean in the context and has a public
> refreshAll() method to refresh all beans in the scope by clearing the
> target cache. The /refresh endpoint exposes this functionality (over
> HTTP or JMX). To refresh an individual bean by name, there is also a
> refresh(String) method.
>
> To expose the /refresh endpoint, you need to add following
> configuration to your application:
>
> management:   endpoints:
> web:
> exposure:
> include: refresh

So I'm guessing the refresh actuator endpoint needs to be enabled otherwise it won't work, right?

But I have a microservice that is configured as follows but it is working completely correct and when configmap changes, the value gets updated.

`bootstrap.yaml`:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    kubernetes:
      reload:
        enabled: true
        mode: polling
        strategy: refresh
      config:
        name: foo
```

`application.yaml`:

```
management:
  endpoint:
    health:
      show-details: "ALWAYS"
      probes:
        enabled: true
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: metrics, health, caches, restart
```

As you can see, there is no refresh endpoint enabled. How is it working properly then?

Comment: Refresh scope does not need the actuator endpoint to function.

Comment: Then how it is receiving new values from configmap?

Comment: IIRC there is a scheduled method